# Macromedia sqlserver jdbc driver object has been closed: error only when running simultaneous requests

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am seeing this error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed.
```

Some other threads mentioned that restarting CF or resetting DSN should sort it out. It did not sorted after the restart. Also my problem looks weird.
I encounter this issue when I run identical url from 2 different browsers immediately one after the other and I see the issue in which the first request was run. If I run the page stand alone, it works.
If it is kind of DB deadlock then it should be similar type of error, why such error then?
Edit: I have little more information. The changes on the page were made so that queries running in a loop were carried over to a SP. Loops are run through temp tables (table variables, earlier chose cursor, but they eat lot of memory. Unfortunately not feasible to forgo these loops) So when that code for SP is removed from CF, it works fine when page is called from different browsers at the same time (though sometimes there are deadlocks in prod with this and these deadlocks were the reason to take SP approach). But as soon as SP is included it starts to throw this error. 
Is there something in CF jdbc drivers which is different for a query vs SP call?
SQL server is 2012.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, have you done a restart of the DB service or server? I am wondering if it ran out of memory

Comment: @JamesAMohler, let me try that.

Comment: Does it only happen with a particular query(s) or *any* query?

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL Server logs? Do they show the connection attempts? Does the CF service account user (hopefully not SQL sa) have permissions to the tables or objects you're querying?

Comment: @Ageax, there is no way to know as there are about 50+ queries on the page and one stored procedure.

Comment: @Shawn, I will check with SQL server logs. But the same URL if I access from a browser, it works. Only when simultaneously same url is called from 2 different browsers, it throw this error in one of them. Error is very consistent, reproducible. It happens on the browser from which it is called first.

Comment: There's should also be a logging setting from the CF DSN.  Just check the box and enter a path for the log file. Under "Log Activity"

Comment: Does it only happen with that one url, or with others too? The fact that it is consistent, suggests it might be an issue with one specific query on that page.